# Pixel in e-mails that sent to see if read or not

Tags: php, email

I build a "GIF" Pixel in my e-mail I sent via PHP.
but, if the user not "Allow Pictures" I can't see if he read it or not,
there is some other good way to improve the pixel working without "allow pictures" from the user side?

I want that if he opening the mail, and the mail is not depending on his some settings he has in his mail program, he will shoot the pixel...

any advice?

thanks.

Comment: Instead of forcing users to break their privacy, you can simply ask: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3798 This will be deactivated in many mail programs, as well. Spammers just destroyed this kind of feature for the internet.

Answer (score 4):

That's the whole point of mail clients not downloading images from untrusted sources. They can be used to track if emails have been read.

You could possibly include a link to your website with an address specific token to track users which click through to your website via the email.

Comment: so threre if some solution for that?

Comment: @John No. I don't want spammers knowing my email address is active, for example.

Answer (score 1):

The **entire reason** why email clients block image downloads is to protect the recipient's privacy. That is, the *reason* images are blocked is to prevent you finding out who read your email.

Please don't be evil.

Comment: I'm not evil... I just want if they read or not, INT(1) = 0/1 that's it, I'm not saving the ip, time etc'... if I using Iframe tag?

Comment: **Any** trick you use to load external content from an email can be used to track the IPs of people who have read your email - regardless of what your intention is. Therefore all such tricks have equal potential for evil.

Comment: Just to add to the answer here. Even if it did work, it wouldn't give the OP any useful information at all with regards to if the mail was read or not. I often click a mail just to display it in the preview pane and see the headlines of a newsletter or so. That would mark it as read but in reality I may not read it at all or I may do it later.